# array of chars in C++

Tags: c++, string, char

Why, when I have the following code, I can explicitly say `cout << a;` and it will print me the whole string, but when I use an array of integers it will instead give me the address of my pointer?

```
char * a;
a=new char [5];
strcpy(a,"foo");
cout << a;
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Note that the `new` is bad: `char a[] = "foo";`

Comment: @chris: No, `std::string a = "foo";`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Quite right. It never even crossed my mind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::ostream& operator<<` has [overloads for different parameter types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt). When passed a `char*`, it treats it as a null-terminated string and prints the characters. When passed pointers to other built-in types, it prints their address.

You can jig things up to get `std::cout` to output some garbage by passing it a `char*` that is *not* a null terminated string:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  char word[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
  int n = 42; // some non-zero data
  std::cout << word << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Undefined Behavior much?

Answer (score 3):

Because `operator<<` is overloaded for char arrays. It treats them as a C-string.

This is not the case for other arrays, which is why you just get the address.